# Redirecting domains, from 301 to a 302 to a 200

Tags: http-status-code-301, http-status-code-302

So did some checking (https://httpstatus.io/) and noticed that some of my domain are redirecting from a 301 to a 200 (what we want) and a couple of them are redirecting from a 301 to a 302 to a 200. All redirects are permanetly. Is this bad in some way ?

Comment: Bad for what? User experience? Response times? Google results? If you can prevent it; do so. Otherwise... I don't think it is the end of the world ;-) Ask yourself why are you redirecting and how you can minimise it.

Comment: bad for google perhaps?